# Query Products based on stock count in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, spree

I'm using Spree for a E-Commerce application and while displaying the list of products to the consumer, I need to include a query based on number of stock items for the product.

The condition is this: I need to only show the products which have a stock count > 2 (sum of stock count of all the variants).

So, I need to add a scope here - https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product/scopes.rb

The problem is that the scope needs to play well with other scopes and also needs to work with the option distinct => true (dont want to break other parts of the app)

The scope can be like this:

```
add_search_scope :with_valid_stock do |values|
  joins(:stock_items).where(condition)
```

the "condition" has to be the sum of stock of all the variants being greater than 2. Any help with the best way to write the condition will be helpful

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgresql.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my answer below?